# Should I be concerned with mongoose/mongodb and its amount of 'connections' being made/held?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

**Overview:**
I have built a production forum software and I am growing concerned with 'current connections' and scale-ability and I recently refactored how my database handles connections which may be incorrect?

**Atlas:**
I am using mongoDB atlas, and I recently got a warning for 'maximum connections' (at 100) and I upgraded the server but it is of great concern with only a small production use but the amount of connections (and growing) that scaling seems like it'll be problematic

**Attempted solution:** 
I tried to dispose of connections as soon as the query was over.

```
const connectMongoDB = (req, res, next) => {
    // Add setting to stop creating connection if no mongo query is being made within the route
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) return next();
    mongoose.connect(config.database.mongo.connection, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        socketTimeoutMS: 50000,
        reconnectTries: 30,
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
    }, () => next());
};


const disconnectFromMongoDB = (req, res, next) => {
    res.on('finish', () => setTimeout(() => mongoose.connection.close(), 2000));
    return next();
};
```

These are middleware, one runs before and after a route respectively, the timeout was needed as sometimes (not consistently reproducible) mongoose would error out with 'topology destroyed' and this timeout fixed this issue. I believed this would fix the issue, but my connections are steadily growing in atlas (175, at a max of 350), as shown below.
[image]
Another concern is command vs query amount as seen here 
[image]

I worry my connection management is wrong and/or the database scaling is way greater than I initially thought.

I also close the connection on the process EXIT as advised, but this seems to be a very intimidating problem, feels with such a reasonably small production environment, that this increase is intimidating to say the least

Any advice

some of my queries include;

- Is this something ive caused with bad connection management?
- Can this be eleviated/fixed programmantically
- Did I pick potentially the wrong database type (NoSQL)
- Is this a problem with atlas/does atlas not scale in an ideal manner VS hosting on a bunch of VPS etc or another mongo host provider

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a problem with the use of mongoose. You only need to call the `mongoose.connect` when your program init. And then use the `models` to do the CRUD operations. Here is the simple example from the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

const kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save().then(() => console.log('meow'));
```

Also, you can set the `poolSize` options to limit the connections to your mongo server

Comment: Thats how I was originally doing mongoose connections but was concerned with the growing amount of connections

Comment: @Cacoon Try the `poolSize` option